# Swift Core Data with for loop only saving last item in array

Tags: for-loop, core-data

One Gymnast to Many Meets. Can someone provide some info on how I can set meet for each gymnast.  It prints each gymnast in array but the meet only gets assigned to last gymnast in array.

```
newMeet.meetName = "Winter Classic"
newMeet.meetDate = "Sat October 26, 2016"
newMeet.meetDateSort = "2016-09-26"
newMeet.meetTime = "02:00 PM"
newMeet.meetLocation = "Phoenix, AZ"
newMeet.meetStatus = "Active"

let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Gymnast")

request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isActive = %@", "Yes")        
do {

            let results = try AD.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Gymnast]

            for result in results {

                let newMeets = result.meets?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableSet

                newMeets.addObject(newMeet)

                result.meets = newMeets.copy() as? NSSet
                print("\(result.fullName!)")
            }


        } catch {

            fatalError("Failed to save data")

        }

       AD.saveContext()

       self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: are you sure you have properly setup the "to many" relationship?  If not every time you assign the meet to a gymnast, it will take it away from the previous relationship

Comment: I believe I have, if I seed a group of test gymnasts during load and assign each the meet it appears to be what I want. I can then click on a gymnast and list all associated meets.

Answer (score 1):

You describe the relationship as one `Gymnast` to many `Meet`s. If it's a one-to-many relationship, that implies that each `Meet` can only be associated with a single `Gymnast`, although each `Gymnast` can be associated with more than one `Meet`.

If your description of the relationship is correct, then what you're seeing is exactly what would be expected. Since each `Meet` can only have one `Gymnast`, each pass through the loop reassigns that relationship from the one set in the previous pass.

I'm guessing that the relationship should be many-to-many, not one-to-many, since each `Meet` can presumably involve more than one `Gymnast`.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  Maybe you could answer one more question.  I did have it many to many and I can associate meet to each with for loop at bottom, but when I have many to many I can't seem to understand how to select one user and display their specific meets, that is why I went back to one to many.

Comment: What can I use for nspredicate?
self.fetchedResultsController = nil       
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Meet")
let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "meetName", ascending: true)
        
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1]
        
//let filter = NSPredicate(format: "gymnasts.fullName == %@", "\(selectedGymnast.fullName!)")
        
//fetchRequest.predicate = filter
let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: AD.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

Comment: Can you post that as a separate question? Both the question and the answer involve some code, and it's hard to read (and write) code in StackOverflow comments.